# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showOuterShadow' in package

Tags: android, gauge

I am Developing an application that consists of a gauge view. I found code from here https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView
I am getting an error of No resource identifier found forattribute'showOuterShadow' in package 
 'org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo. I added the library in the java build path of the project  but it was still occurring please help me to solve this  this is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="20dp" >

   <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView  <!--Error occurring here-->
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        gauge:showOuterShadow="true"
        gauge:showOuterRim="false"
        gauge:showNeedle="false"
        gauge:showRanges="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textUnit="%" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added library to project from Properties->Android-> Add libs ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude and i didn't check that.Later i checked it i cleared my problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is so ridiculous to answer my own question:
i didn't add the library in my android project that is 
 YOUR PROJECT->RIGHTCLICK->POPERTIES->ANDROID->CLICK "ADD"->SELECT LIBRARY->CLICK "APPLY"->CLICK "OK"->RUN YOUR PROJECT